# Monitor flickers in a MSI U120/Wind U100

Tags: graphics

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my computer. It came with Windows XP. My computer is an MSI U120. Now when I turn on my computer and go into Ubuntu my screen brightness is on low. When I then turn up the brightness the screen starts to flicker. It also shows the indicator of how much brightness my screen has. My friend talked me through "backlight" but it didn't help. Any other ideas?

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the relevant information(specifically in relation to your video configuration. Thanks!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Years ago I used to have a MSI Wind U100 and it suffered from the same issue. There's a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hal-info/+bug/415023) - look through the comments there, one of the proposed solutions is to update the netbook's BIOS, other involve various tweaks to the Gnome power manager.

Comment: Thanks Sergey!!!!!
I used one of the suggestions from the bug report page [comment #347](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hal-info/+bug/415023/comments/347)


Here is the command that worked for me.

sudo chmod u-w /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness

Thanks for responding so quickly!!!!!